# Why is a class variable defined first before turned into an instance variable in this code?

Tags: python, python-2.7, properties

when learning python property decorator in this [link](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/property), I stumbled upon following lines of code:

```
class Celsius:
    def __init__(self, temperature = 0):
        self.temperature = temperature       

    def to_fahrenheit(self):
        return (self.temperature * 1.8) + 32

    def get_temperature(self):
        print("Getting value")
        return self._temperature

    def set_temperature(self, value):
        if value < -273:
            raise ValueError("Temperature below -273 is not possible")
        print("Setting value")
        self._temperature = value

    temperature = property(get_temperature,set_temperature)
```

this code basically let you modify/add restraint to a `Celsius` object, without having anybody who inherited `Celsius` class refactor their code.

why does it define a class variable `temperature` first, rather than just let `self.temperature = property(get_temperature,set_temperature)` and done?

EDIT: Due to conflict opinions in comments, I will now restore the code to original state, regardless if there is a typo, to make it easy for people read this afterwards.

Comment: should be 'self._tem...' in `__init__`? `_temperature` does not initialized at first

Comment: And I remember that property only works with new style class and object.

Comment: there is typo in in the above link you provided.  you need to update your code according to the last piece of code  . it should be `self._temperature...` in `__init__`

Comment: @Jacky That is not a typo. Note that with the above code you could do this without an error, which is bad: `t=Celsius(-500)`. Typically the initializer should use the property to get or set the private variable just like any other method would.

Comment: @RickTeachey so are you saying the above code was not using the property approach correctly?

Comment: @Hiagara it is not initializing the property correctly, yes, but to be more specific.

Comment: The original code (displayed now) resolved that particular problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer lies in the [descriptor protocol and attribute lookup order](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html). If you did this:

```
class Celsius:
    def __init__(self, temperature): 
        self.temperature = property(get_temperature,set_temperature)
        self.temperature = temperature
# etc etc
```

It will not behave the way you expect. At all.

```
t = Celsius(100)
t.temperature = -500 # NO ERROR! BROKEN!
```

WHY? Because you overwrote the property object with the number that was provided to the initializer. Observe:

```
get = lambda *args: None # dummy getter
set = lambda *args: None # dummy setter
p = property(get, set) # dummy property
```

A property should be an instance of `Property`:

```
print(type(p).__name__)
# Property
```

But your temperature isn't a property anymore:

```
print(type(t.temperature).__name__)
# int
```

You overwrote it with this line:

```
self.temperature = temperature 
# note that temperature is an int or float
```

Sprinkle some `print` statements to see what is going on:

```
class Celsius:
    def __init__(self, temperature): 
        self.temperature = property(get_temperature,set_temperature)
        print(type(self.temperature).__name__) # Property
        self.temperature = temperature
        print(type(self.temperature).__name__) # no longer a Property!
# etc etc
```

Therefore, the property object needs to be stored at the *class level* so it doesn't get overwritten at the *instance level*. When a *class level* property object is accessed at the instance level, the descriptor protocol is automatically invoked (a `Property` is a type of descriptor; descriptors have unusual behavior so go study them carefully).

Learn more about class level objects vs. instance level objects at this [much more detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645/static-class-variables-in-python/27568860#27568860).

Also note that the temperature needs to be set *in the initializer* using the property. Do **not** do this:

```
class Celsius: 
    def __init__(self, temperature):
        self._temperature = temperature
```

Using this code you could do this without an error, which is bad: `t=Celsius(-500)`. Typically the initializer should use the property to get or set the private variable just like any other method would:

```
        self.temperature = temperature
```

Now an invalid initial temperature will cause an error, as expected.

Comment: to me, looks like there is indeed a typo, because after instantiate the class as c, doing c.temperature would only output "Setting Value" if it is self._temperature in __init__ method.

Comment: You are mistaken.

Comment: in what sense, if I may ask?  in fact at this moment I am highly doubting this original code is idiomatic at all.

Comment: It's obviously old. But only because it is not using the `@property` decorator.  You are mistaken because if you do not use the setter inside of the initializer,  you will be able to initialize with invalid values, ie, `Celsius(-500)`.

Comment: is the correct way to use setter in initializer adding `self.set_temperature(temperature)` in `__init__` method?

Comment: No, just use it the original way.

Answer (score 1):

In the snippet above there are two things addressed:

**1. Setting temperature during object creation using parameterized constructor.**

`def __init__(self, temperature = 0):`

In this case Celsius with temperature 8 will be created as:

```
t = Celsius(8)
```

**2. Setting and retrieving temperature using object property using**

`temperature = property(get_temperature,set_temperature)`

In this case Celsius with temperature 8 will be created, set/retrieved as:

```
t = Celsius()
t.set_temperature(8)
print t.get_temperature()
```

Answer (score 0):

Because methods *are* class properties. And `self` does not exist in that scope.

Note, that code is very out of date; you should use `property` as a decorator:

```
@property
def temperature(self):
    print("Getting value")
    return self._temperature

@temperature.setter
def set_temperature(self, value):
    if value < -273:
        raise ValueError("Temperature below -273 is not possible")
    print("Setting value")
    self._temperature = value
```